# How do i prove my Best-first search in prolog

Tags: algorithm, search, prolog, greedy

I have the following problem.

[image: Traversal Graph]

I need to do a Best-First Search on the above graph in prolog for Node A to Node E

I have done it by hand and have the following 4 paths

A(0) - C(6) - G(9) - I(13) - H(15) - E(16)

A(0) - C(6) - G(9) - I(13) - H(15) - B(19) - D(24) - E(26)

A(0) - B(1) - H(5) - E(6)

A(0) - B(1) - D(6) - E(8)

Obviously the best path is the 3rd one (A(0) - B(1) - H(5) - E(6)).

I need to implement a prolog best-first search program to prove this is the case.

I think I would use the facts

```
connects(a, c, 6).
connects(a, b, 1).
connects(b, h, 4).
```

etc etc..

But after that I am stuck, If you could help me or even direct me to a website/youtube video of how to implement this I would be over the moon.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `best fist` doesn't sound so good...

Comment: What is the difference of `best first` with `connects/3` ordered from the largest to the smallest?